# Google API Python Client Call with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have a python code on my desktop where I call Google APIs to get some data. I am trying to deploy it on AWS Lambda to run it periodically but I and running into some issues. Below are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded google package using pip3 install google-api-python-client -t . Zipped this folder and uploaded it to a layer in AWS Lambda
2. Linked the layer with my function but when I am trying to execute the lambda function, I get the following error:

"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'googleapiclient'",

In my code I have the following import statement:

`from googleapiclient.discovery import build`

Please let me know if I am missing something and how to debug this.

Regards,
Dbeings

Comment: Verify that your Lambda Layer was correctly [structured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path). I'd test with a different Python package first, e.g. pillow or requests, that is commonly installed in Lambda Layers and hence you'll find some help on the web.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed a structuring issue. I changed folder name from 'googleAPIClient' to 'Python' and it worked for googleAPI . But now running into some issues with standard python package imports sand using AWS Data wrangler library with google API due to layer size restriction. Will research on that separately.

Answer (score 0):

You typically receive this error when your Lambda environment can't find the specified library in the Python code. This is because Lambda isn't prepackaged with all third party python libraries.

in your local environment "googleapiclient" are compiled and available during runtime but it's not available in lambda runtime.

To resolve this error, create a deployment package(pre-compilied/zip) or Lambda layer that includes the libraries that you want to use in your Python code for Lambda.

best of luck

Comment: It was structuring issue. I changed folder name from 'googleAPIClient' to 'Python' and it worked for googleAPI .  It now appears, I cant use AWS data wrangler package as I am exceeding Layer size limit. So, I downloaded pandas using PIP to same folder. But now I am get a numpy dependency error though numpy was downloaded as part of pandas install. Two folders: numpy, numpy-1.22.0.dist-info : correct version as per error. 

Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: ...Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. ...
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'